# through image name display image in custom tab in admin grid

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

hello everyone i want to display the uploaded image my code is below
info.php

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'image',
            'label'    => __('image'),
            'renderer'  => 'Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer\LogoImage',
            'required'     => true,

        ]
    );
```

logoimage.php

```
<?php

     namespace 
    Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer;

  class LogoImage extends  
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer {

protected $_storeManager;

protected $_fileSystem;

protected $_modelData;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\AlllayoutFactory $modelData,
    array $data = []) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->_modelData = $modelData;
    $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
}
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
    $id = $this->_getValue($row);
    $filepath = $this->_fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images');
    $data = $this->_modelData->load($id);
    foreach($data as $file)
    {   
        echo "<img src='".$filepath."pub/media/images".$file['image']."' height='30' width='30' />";
    }
}

 }
```

[image]